# If x and y are list and y =x. What is the value of x and y?

Tags: python, list, variables, data-structures, integer

I have some questions about the below code and it's respective output.

**Code**:

```
x = [5,6] 
y = x 
y.append(6) 
print(x,y)
```

**Output**: `[5,6,6] [5,6,6]`

**My Question**: Why is the value of `x` equal to `y`?
Can anyone explain the logic behind this output.

Comment: `x` and `y` refer to the same list object

Comment: You create a list `[5, 6]` and bind the name `x` to it. The additionally you bind the name `y` to it. Now you have one list you can access with two different names.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: and if you just need to copy the data to a new list you can do `x.copy()`

Answer (score 0):

In python variables data values through references. A reference is a name that refers to the specific location in memory of a value (object). References take the form of variables, attributes, and items.data values through references. A reference is a name that refers to the specific location in memory of a value (object). References take the form of variables, attributes, and items.